# Golang regex match +-/*

Tags: regex, go

I tried this:

`re_operator := regexp.MustCompile("^(+|-|*|/)")`

I get this:

```
panic: regexp: Compile(`^(+|-|*|/)`): error parsing regexp: missing argument to repetition operator: `+`
```

It's literally impossible to Google an answer to this question, not to mention it varies for every language and version. I'm about to use an if else. Escape sequences are also a pain. Should I try escaping my escape sequence?

Unhelpful answer:
[Regular expression to match digits and basic math operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631820/regular-expression-to-match-digits-and-basic-math-operators)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Escape RegEx meta characters:

```
MustCompile("^(\\+|-|\\*|/)")
```

Or better yet, use a bracket expression:

```
MustCompile("^[-+*/]")
```

Note in bracket expressions you must put the hyphen at first or at last.

Comment: Thanks but only the top one works. Will accept answer in mandatory 8 minutes.

Comment: @asdf Second one fixed.